# CentOs downloading from direc link return 404 Not Found

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos

After uploading some files into `public_html` with nested directory when i try to test download links from browser, that return `404 Not Found`

`pwd` output command:

```bsh
/home/pishguy/public_html/audio/quran/01.FATİHA - AYET AYET/DÜŞÜK KALİTE
[root@server DÜŞÜK KALİTE]#
```

`ls` command result:

```bsh
[root@server DÜŞÜK KALİTE]# ls -a -l
total 68
drwxr-xr-x. 2 pishguy pishguy    29 Mar 31 10:11 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 pishguy pishguy  4096 Mar 31 10:11 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 pishguy pishguy 64814 Nov 24 12:21 FATİHA 001.mp3
```

as you can see i have a `FATİHA 001.mp3` in this path: `/home/pishguy/public_html/audio/quran/01.FATİHA - AYET AYET/DÜŞÜK KALİTE`.

full path:

```bsh
/home/pishguy/public_html/audio/quran/01.FATİHA - AYET AYET/DÜŞÜK KALİTE/FATİHA 001.mp3
```

then this direct link should be work without any problem:

```
www.pishguy.ir/audio/quran/01.FATİHA - AYET AYET/DÜŞÜK KALİTE/FATİHA 001.mp3
```

or this encoded url link:

```
http://www.pishguy.ir/audio/quran/01.FAT%C4%B0HA%20-%20AYET%20AYET/D%C3%9C%C5%9E%C3%9CK%20KAL%C4%B0TE/FAT%C4%B0HA%20001.mp3
```

but the server return this page:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

TIP:

i should have this path with this directories and i can't change them such as file name, file path or file directory name

Answer (score 0):

That particular URL returns a 404:

`http://www.pishguy.ir/audio/quran/01.FAT%C4%B0HA%20-%20AYET%20AYET/D%C3%9C%C5%9E%C3%9CK%20KAL%C4%B0TE/FAT%C4%B0HA%20001.mp3`

However, the parent directory is searchable:

`http://www.pishguy.ir/audio/quran/01.FAT%c4%b0HA%20-%20AYET%20AYET/D%c3%9c%c5%9e%c3%9cK%20KAL%c4%b0TE/`

And judging from that URL, there is nothing in the directory. Often times this is a permissions issue, but the permissions look fine at first glance (`0755` for the `.` and `..` directories, `0644` for the file itself). Another possible explanation is that SELinux is denying apache/httpd access to the file. SELinux logs could determine that, and updating the context for the file should fix that:

`# chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/pishguy/public_html/audio/quran/01.FATİHA - AYET AYET/DÜŞÜK KALİTE/FATİHA 001.mp3`

(the `-Z` option passed to `ls` should also show you relevant SELinux attributes of the files in question, a la `ls -lahZ .`)

There are other files that are visible/downloadable in other directories, such as:

`http://www.pishguy.ir/audio/quran/05.MA%c4%b0DE/MAI%cc%87DE%20000.mp3`

I would compare the permissions and SELinux bits at one of these working locations, to the location that is currently not working, and troubleshoot further from there.